# How can I maintain an up-to-date database of TLD classifications using the IANA Root Zone Database?

Tags: database, dns, projects-and-solutions, tld, iana

I'm working on a project where I need to determine the type or classification of a Top-Level Domain (TLD). This classification includes categories like generic TLDs, country code TLDs, and more. The challenge is to keep this database continuously updated as the IANA/ICANN adds, removes, or reclassifies TLDs over time.

I've identified the IANA Root Zone Database as a valuable source for this information, as it is regularly updated to reflect changes made by ICANN/IANA. However, I'm unsure about how to access and use this database effectively for my project.

**Here are the specific questions I have:**

can anyone provide insights on accessing IANA Root Zone Database. The list of TLD's with the type classification is found in https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db. but, is it possible to access this database to integrate into my project and if so, how? I couldn't find any source to download the data with TLD type classified as shown in the above link.

so far from what I've know there is a link root zone files provided by IANA https://www.internic.net/domain/root.zone which doesn't seems to contain any details regarding the type of the TLD.

I want to ensure that my project maintains an accurate and up-to-date record of TLD classifications, aligning with the authoritative information provided by the IANA Root Zone Database.I'd also welcome if anyone suggesting an alternative datasource that would help me to achieve my challange.

Thank you for any guidance or recommendations you can provide to help me achieve this goal.